# Checkbox requirements for random generator not going into sum

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a password generator that when you hit generate, you get a password. It has 4 options with 0.5 chance to change a character generated at length if checked. When I add the checkboxes for NUMBERS and SYMBOLS it stops working.

```js
const generateBtn = document.getElementById('generate')
const passwordDisplay = document.getElementById('passwordInput')

const checkUpper = document.getElementById('checkUppercase')
const checkLower = document.getElementById('checkLowercase')
const checkNumber = document.getElementById('checkNumber')
const checkSymbol = document.getElementById('checkSymbol')

function rangeSlider() {
  let slider = document.getElementById('slider')
  let output = document.getElementById('numCount')
  output.innerHTML = slider.value
  slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value
  }
}

function generatePassword() {
  passwordArray = []
  let length = document.getElementById('slider').value
  let password = ''
  let upper = checkUppercase.checked
  let lower = checkLowercase.checked
  let number = checkNumber.checked
  let symbol = checkSymbol.checked

  let characters = `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`;
  let uppercaseCharacters = `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

  if (upper && Math.random() < 0.5) {
    characters += uppercaseCharacters
  }
  if (lower && Math.random() < 0.5) {
    characters = characters.replace(uppercaseCharacters, '')
  }
  if (number && Math.random() < 0.5) {
    characters += `0123456789`
  }
  if (symbol && Math.random() < 0.5) {
    characters += `!@#$%^&*()_+~\`|}{[]\:;?><,./-=`
  }

  let charactersLength = characters.length;
  let counter = 0;

  while (counter < length) {
    password += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength))
    counter++
  }

  passwordDisplay.value = password

}

rangeSlider()
generateBtn.addEventListener('click', generatePassword)
```

I'm not sure when I add the two variables of number and symbol, it stops generating.Thank you for any help

Comment: Why do you remove the uppercase characters if they checked lower? If they check both upper and lower, doesn't that mean they want both?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to tackle that honestly

Comment: Start with an empty string, then add each type based on the checkboxes.

Comment: But what's supposed to happen if the 50% chances don't select any type?

Comment: That's true too. I was afraid it would force everything uppercase or lowercase if checked

Comment: Why does checking the box only give a 50% chance that those will be included?

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would stop working when you add the number and symbols checkboxes. Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: What would be a more appropriate approach to including, say, the uppercase, but not forcing it to dominate?

Comment: Please add the HTML to the snippet so we can try to run it.

Comment: Why would it dominate? Are you worried that you'll get too many letters because there are 26 letters and only 10 digits?

Comment: I was worried that if I checked "included uppercase" all the generator would produce would be uppercase instead of intermitently

Comment: But you're not doing the probability for each character generated. If the 50% goes the other way you won't get ANY uppercase letters at all.

Comment: Why did you think that? You're concatenating all the selected types, then it will select randomly from that collection.

Comment: A failure on my part. Thank you for helping me understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the Math.random() checks for numbers and symbols so that they are included in the character set if the corresponding checkboxes are checked.

Try this

```
function generatePassword() {
passwordArray = []
let length = document.getElementById('slider').value
let password = ''
let upper = checkUppercase.checked
let lower = checkLowercase.checked
let number = checkNumber.checked
let symbol = checkSymbol.checked

let characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
let uppercaseCharacters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

if (upper) {
    characters += uppercaseCharacters
}
if (lower) {
    characters += 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
}
if (number) {
    characters += '0123456789'
}
if (symbol) {
    characters += '!@#$%^&*()_+~`|}{[]\\:;?><,./-='
}

let charactersLength = characters.length;
let counter = 0;

while (counter < length) {
    password += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength))
    counter++
}

passwordDisplay.value = password
```

}

Comment: The initial value of `characters` should be empty. Otherwise you have lowercase characters twice.

Comment: The question says there should be a 0.5 chance to get a character of the specific type if a checkbox is checked. That's what the Math.random call is for.